# POCO - Entity Framework - Persisting only scalar properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, poco

This may be little weird, but I want to persist only the scalar properties of an object to the database. eg. let's say I have 2 tables/entities "User" and "UserOrder". "User" entity has "FirstName", "LastName", "UserOrders" (collection of "UserOrder"). Now, I get a "User" object which has some UserOrders in it. I need to persist **only** the scalar properties of the the "User" i.e.FirstName & LastName.

If I do context.Users.AddObject(user), it is adding "UserOrders" also to the db (which I don't want). Does creating a new "User" object and copying all the scalars in to that is my only option (or) can we explicitly tell EF to persist only the scalars even though there are other navigational properties in it?

The reason I ask is I have to persist "User" and "UserOrders" separately in 2 different steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very bizarre - i'm sure you have your reasons for doing this.

You could **remove the navigational properties (e.g non-scalar) from the model**, so you can persist the two objects seperately.

Step 1 -  *Adding a User:*

```
var user = new User { };
user.UserOrders = new UserOrders { }; // compiler error! no property exists. good!
ctx.Users.AddObject(user); // only user scalar properties added
```

Step 2 - *Adding a UserOrder - which still needs to "relate" to a User:*

```
var relatedUser = ctx.Users.First(); // grab the user related to this order
var userOrder = new UserOrder { UserId = relatedUser.UserId }; // explicitly set the FK
ctx.UserOrders.AddObject(userOrder); // UserOrder added with appropriate FK
```

That *should* work - i haven't tried it before, but give it a go.

Keep in mind the drawback of this approach is you will not be able to eager/lazy load `UserOrders` when you request a `User` - you will have to manually join on the FK using LINQ.

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain why you need to do this in 2 separate steps?  Either way, if you have a limited number of navigational properties, you could simply store in another variable & remove:

```
var orders = user.Orders;
user.Orders = null;
context.Users.AddObject(user);

...

context.Orders.AddObject(orders); // You might have to do these one by one
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually, User and UserOrders was just an example. We have a complex system where it requires storing in 2 steps because some additional validation needs to happen in the interim. As there are more navigational properties than scalar and since I will be using the so called "User" object again in the code, I think it's better to create a new Object than holding the references to navigation properties. Can we explicitly set in EF to store only Scalars (like ApplyCurrentValues does while updating)?

Comment: @Jonna: I'm not familiar with anything like that, though it could exist.